# How to create a brush using an SVG with paper.js?

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I have a simple canvas set up with paper.js that creates a path when a user clicks and drags the mouse. I would like to then stretch an SVG along this path to create a brush effect. (In the same manner as Adobe Illustrators "[stretch to fit stroke length](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/illustrator/using/brushes.html)" property on their brushes) Does anyone know how I might achieve this? Example of brush effect in adobe illustrator I want to recreate in canvas:

[image]

I've imported the brush as an svg but path.importSVG(brush) isn't doing anything. I'm new to paper.js and not sure where to begin.

[Sketch of where I am so far](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

```
// Brush
var brush = '<svg[...]</svg>'
// Symbol
var symbol =  new Symbol(project.importSVG(brush, {
  expandShapes: true
}));

// The minimum distance the mouse has to drag before firing the next onMouseDrag event
tool.minDistance = 5;

var path;

/* Click */
function onMouseDown(event) {
  // Create a new path and select it
  path = new Path();
  path.strokeColor = '#ffffff';
  path.selected = true;

  // Add a segment to the path where you clicked
  path.add(event.point);
}

/* Drag */
function onMouseDrag(event) {
  // Every drag event, add a segment to the path at the position of the mouse
  path.add(event.point);
}

/* Up */
function onMouseUp(event) {
  var placed = symbol.place(event.point);
  placed.scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: This is a morph effect, not just a brush. I don't know paperjs so can't help more, but that sounds like a non trivial task you are after.

Comment: @Kaiido Yep, it’s slowly dawning on me how difficult this may be 

Comment: Unfortunately, Paper.js definitely not offers such a feature. So you'll have to either find a library that can help you with it or implement the algorithm yourself. I'm quite sure that this kind of algorithm must be documented somewhere on the web. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just import your SVG in a new path on each mouse drag (I would advice adding the SVG every *n* events, and / or use low opacity), in your `onMouseDrag` function, but for better performances you can use [Symbols](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/working-with-symbols/).

```
var path = new Path();
// [...]
path.importSVG(brush);

// Create a symbol from the path:
var symbol = new Symbol(path);
const N_EVENTS_TO_SKIP = 10;
var n = 0;
/* Drag */
function onMouseDrag(event) {
    // skip some events
    n++;
    if(n < N_EVENTS_TO_SKIP) {
       return;
    }
    n = 0;
    
    // place the symbol
    var placed = symbol.place(event.point);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arthur but unfortunately I don't think it's what I'm looking for. This creates multiple versions of the SVG whereas I would like a single SVG to stretch out the length of the path. This is probably unclear so I've added an image of the effect I want to recreate to my question.